# Attach image to news in django admin when user has alternatives

Tags: django, image, django-admin

I have Django model for storing news, shortly

```
class News(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField('content')
```

Editors may attach image to every peace of news applying one of 3 methods:

- Upload via models.ImageField()
- Fill in url of image from external source
- Choose image which has already been uploaded in Photo Gallery (planning to use django photologue)

The main question I wonder how to design database to store the image path and photo id simultaneously.

Also how this should look like in django admin. What I need to extend.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using a HTML editor for this type of project will be quite useful. [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) are pretty good WYSIWYG editors. I have previously used [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for few of my projects and it is amazing when it comes to edit content with images and formatting etc.
[django-ckeditor](https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor) provides a simple integration of ckeditor with django. All of the 3 methods that are required for your project, are easily achievable by this. Hope it helps.

Regarding database design: If you do decide to use ckeditor, you won't need any change in database design, as the data is stored as HTML within the database. The image path is stored within the HTML so you will not have to worry about it

Comment: Yes, I know about this possibility but it's not a good variant because an image is always located in the same place of HTML. Using WYSIWYG editors presupposes manual page makeup. Anyway I keep it in mind thanks